# Scanning a text file and storing it in an array list is giving a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, arrays, file, filereader

Hi I am trying to read in a text file which I am getting from a text box and reading it in a different class. My first class Gui which is supposed to output that text file is giving me an error.

```
public class Gui {
private static JFrame frame;
private static JToolBar toolbar;
private static JTextField input;
private static JTextArea output;
private static JScrollPane scrollPane;
private static JButton read, clear;
public static ArrayList<String> Lines;
private static final int HOR_SIZE = 400;
private static final int VER_SIZE = 150;
public static reader reader = new reader();
private static File file;
private static ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

public static void initComponents(){

    frame = new JFrame("CS-371 - File Reader");
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    toolbar = new JToolBar();
    input = new JTextField();
    read = new JButton("Read File");
    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    output = new JTextArea();
    output.setSize(HOR_SIZE, VER_SIZE);
    //output.setEditable(false);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);           
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(HOR_SIZE, VER_SIZE));
    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(HOR_SIZE, VER_SIZE));
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(HOR_SIZE, VER_SIZE));


    toolbar.add(input);
    toolbar.add(read);
    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    frame.add(toolbar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(clear, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    toolbar.setFloatable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    initComponents();
    read.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            reader.setPath(input.getText());
            file = new File(input.getText());
            if(!file.isFile()){
                output.setText(reader.checkPath()); 
            }else{
                temp = reader.getFile();
                if(!temp.isEmpty()){
                    for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++){
                        output.setText(temp.get(i).toString()); 
                    }
                }else{
                    output.setText("File empty");
                }
            }
        }

    }); 
    clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            output.setText("");
        }
    });
}
}
```

At the line temp = reader.getFile() this is a Array list that is set up which gets its contents from the method in my reader class.

```
public class reader implements Runnable {
     private Scanner scanner;
     private File file;
     private String path;
     private ArrayList<String> fileContents;
public String getLine(){

    return null;

}
public void setPath(String path){
        this.path = path;
}
public String checkPath(){
    file = new File(path);
    if(file.isFile()){

    }else{
        return "File not found";
    }
    return "";
}
public ArrayList<String> getFile(){
    file = new File(path);
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        String scan = scanner.nextLine();
        fileContents.add(scan);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return fileContents;
}
@Override
public void run() {


}
}
```

The error I'm getting from this class is fileContents.add(scan)
Both are apparently giving null pointer exceptions but I don't know why cause that should be filling my array list then the other array list should have no trouble in setting its contents to the returned array list that it calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize `fileContents` at first as following:

```
private ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Otherwise it's `null` by default

Comment: Thanks cant believe I missed that it was turning me insane! Anyway thanks it works now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to **initialize** your `ArrayList`. That is, actually **create it** at some point.

You could do it either directly on its declaration, like this:

```
private final List<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or using a **constructor**:

```
public reader() {
    this.fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

---

On a side note, the convention in Java in to **capitalize the class names**. Thus, your `reader` class could (should?) be called `Reader`.
And actually, as much as possible, I would also suggest you to avoid using this identifier for your class since **an interface that has the same name already exists** in the Java standard library.

Comment: Yeah that is the reason I lower cased the class name to avoid anything like that I will change the name of the class before I submit it then. And thanks the initializing the arraylist works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
private ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

Comment: Yeah thanks got it now I had a big brain melt and forgot to initialize it :\